# Android-how to send continuous latitude and longitude to the server?

Tags: gps, server, location, latitude-longitude

I continuously get the current location, now I want to send this continuous location to the sever every 1 to 5 sec. How do I do this?

Android code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

TextView txtOutputLat, txtOutputLon;
Location mLastLocation;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
String lat, lon;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    txtOutputLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    txtOutputLon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    buildGoogleApiClient();




}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {


    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(100); // Update location every second

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);


    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        lat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        lon = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());

    }
    updateUI();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    lon = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    updateUI();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

void updateUI() {
    txtOutputLat.setText(lat);
    txtOutputLon.setText(lon);
}
}
```